# Additional spaces to align continuation lines

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

I've started using Flake8 to check my python code, but the one error/warning it always give me which I find a pain to sort is the "continuation line over/under indented".

Flake8 wants my continuation line to align exactly with the starting bracket. So in the example below, Flake8 won't like the first two, but will like the third: (» = 4 spaces, · = single space)

```
let_us_pass.some_function(with_a_lot_of=['strings'], or_other_arguments,
»   »   »   »   »   »   and_another)

let_us_pass.some_function(with_a_lot_of=['strings'], or_other_arguments,
»   »   »   »   »   »   »   and_another)

let_us_pass.some_function(with_a_lot_of=['strings'], or_other_arguments,
»   »   »   »   »   »   ··and_another)
```

So Flake8 doesn't complain about mixing 4-space blocks and single spaces.
All I can find in PEP8 is a comment in an example: `# Hanging indents *may* be indented to other than 4 spaces.`

Does this mean it's frowned upon? Should I stick with clearing all Flake8 warnings (and mixing numbers of spaces), or live with the warnings to maintain 4-space purity.

Comment: Here is the relevant section of PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation

Comment: '(By "tab", I mean I press the tab key and my editor inserts 4 spaces)'—please don't call this a "tab". It's something _entirely_ different. If you're using a bunch of four-space indents plus a few extra spaces you _aren't_ mixing spaces and tabs. There's no way of knowing that there are "different multiples of spaces". That's not really a thing.

Comment: @Chris I'm using different terminology to distinguish between the blocks of four spaces used for strict indentation in Python, and adding extra spaces for visual style. I'll edit it anyway.

Comment: @0x5453 I know. I quoted from that section of PEP8 in the question.

Comment: @thosphor they're all spaces, your editor is just converting TABs for convenience. The very first "yes" example in the link you've been given is `#Aligned with opening delimiter.`, exactly the same as your example 3 in the question. Your first two approaches match the first "No" example of that same section. You don't have a "hanging" indent so your "*may use*" comment doesn't apply.

Comment: @Chris the vast majority of modern text editors use emulated tabs.  they don't convert a "True" tab to anything, when they receive the tab key they insert a number of spaces by default.  Making this point nowadays is clinging to a Tabs vs Spaces holy war/crusade of an era long past.

Comment: @Thunderwood, that's entirely irrelevant and I'm not clinging to a holy war. I'm asking OP to properly describe what's happening instead of obfuscating it by using the wrong terms. The tab _key_ is different from the tab _character_. There's no mixing of spaces and tabs here.

Comment: @Thunderwood except that mixing actual tabs and spaces _will_ throw an error in Python that actually crops up here a bit, and you're making the assumption that they definitely do have an editor doing that. There are people coding in notepad asking questions on here...

Comment: @roganjosh ~~I don't think my first two examples match the "no" section you're talking about in PEP8, since there's no ambiguity introduced by the indentation.~~ Realised I'd missed the crucial bit of one of the "no" examples: "`# Arguments on first line forbidden when not using vertical alignment`"

Comment: It says nothing about ambiguity, it says `# Arguments on first line forbidden when not using vertical alignment.` You have arguments on the first line and only your 3rd example is vertically aligned.

Comment: @roganjosh Fair point.  I forget it isn't just VI and EMACs eccentrics who need to deal with this issue :P

Comment: @Thunderwood, "most of the time nowadays when people say "tabs" it is understood that they mean emulated ones"... "most people don't actually use true tabs anymore" you're making assumptions, and ones that I believe to be untrue. Plenty of people use tabs these days, and even if they didn't, _tab characters still exist_. When a question title says "mixing tabs and spaces", do you honestly think, "oh, I see, they're using some kind of `(n × indent_level + alignment) × ' '` model"?

Comment: @roganjosh Edited my comment. (I meant the second "no" example since it talks about distinguishability)

Comment: @Chris all I'm saying is that emulated tabs are used by the majority of modern text editors.  You know this, I know this.  When a guy says tabs AND THEN CLARIFIES he means emulated ones, there is really ZERO need to jump down his throat in the comments section.  We know what emulated tabs are.  We know they aren't "true" tabs.  No point in being the factoid spouting "Well actually..." guy in the comments

Comment: @Thunderwood, except there _is_ a point in doing this. Stack Overflow is about helping people learn. That includes the OP, who I hope will be more careful talking about tabs in the future (because calling groups of four spaces a "tab" is objectively wrong) and other users, who I hope won't be confused when they read this later. And stop relying on what you think "most" and "the majority" do. You don't know what editor this person is using, or how it's configured. And, again, this isn't just for the OP—it's for everybody else with a similar question in the future. Stop assuming things.

Comment: @Chris My original post was careful in that I had a clarification. Since PEP8 specifies 4-space indentation, I thought it would be easier to talk about this specific question using "tabs" as 4 spaces. As an aside, the only time I've been confused about tabs/spaces is the other way around. I always wondered why there was a war about it since I assumed everyone's editor inserted 2/4/8 spaces when they pressed the tab key.

Comment: @thosphor, I'm going to leave instead of continuing to argue. But the original question title specifically said "mixing tabs and spaces", which tells us something. Then we load the question and halfway through we find that you're actually talking about something entirely different. Your title should clearly summarize your question, and your question should be clear from the start, not from halfway through. Asking questions clearly is the most important thing that askers can do here.

Comment: @Chris your title clarification was helpful, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from a footnote on the relevant [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id17) page:

> Hanging indentation is a type-setting style where all the lines in a paragraph are indented except the first line. In the context of Python, the term is used to describe a style where the opening parenthesis of a parenthesized statement is the last non-whitespace character of the line, with subsequent lines being indented until the closing parenthesis.

```
# Hanging indents *may* be indented to other than 4 spaces.
foo = long_function_name(
  var_one, var_two,
  var_three, var_four)
```

This is not the same case as your example, since you have arguments on the first line.  PEP8 states that you should keep the function arguments vertically aligned, so Flake8 is correct here.  Don't worry about "maintaining 4-space purity" if doing so would violate other PEP8 rules.

If you *really* hate having spaces in non-multiples of 4, you can switch to one of the following styles:

```
# More indentation included to distinguish this from the rest.
def long_function_name(
        var_one, var_two, var_three,
        var_four):
    print(var_one)

# Hanging indents should add a level.
foo = long_function_name(
    var_one, var_two,
    var_three, var_four)
```